# How to fix broken focus when clicking on Notifications in Teams Client from 1:1 Chat Bot Messages? - Focus goes to Activity tab and not Chat

Tags: botframework, microsoft-teams

Set up:

Bot Built via Bot Framework 4.x Sends 1:1 Chat Message-> Microsoft Teams -> Teams Client
User (Desktop Teams client Windows).

BotX sends or replies to a 1:1 Chat message from Teams User.  If the Teams user UI focus is not on the Teams client or if on the Teams client but not on that conversation, the Teams client shows a toast notification (the popup that appears in the system tray).  So far so good.

There appears to have been a recent (mid 2021)  breaking change in Bot Framework or Teams Client behavior, where clicking on the toast notification does not take the user into the chat pane of the BotX conversation.   Instead, the Teams client focus is taken to the Feeds/Activity Tab and the user must again click on the Chat Navigation icon on the Teams client Navigation rail and then again on the specific Bot conversation to view the message.  (The bot has been in use for 2+ years and this behaviour only recently broke)

This broken focus behaviour seems to be only happening with chat messages received from bots.  Reproducible in Windows and Mac clients.  User to user message notifications on the Teams clients work as expected which is clicking takes you immediately to the respective user chat pane.

See screen shots below showing desired vs. actual behavior of MS Teams client when interacting with Bot notifications.

**Question: Any changes to the Bot Framework SDK that would require adding a new setting or flag to the 1-1 Chat Teams messages to let the client know that this is a chat message (and not an Activity Feed)?**

One curious observation is that if the bot is loaded via a deeplink (i.e not installed via a Manifest file) then the Teams client behaviour is proper and as expected.

Notification Popup 1:1 Chat Message from Bot - This aspect is fine

[image: Notification Popup 1:1 Chat Message from Bot - This aspect is fine]

Expected Focus When Clicking on Notification

[image: Expected Focus When Clicking on Notification]

Broken Behaviour

[image: Broken Behaviour]

Answer (score -1):

We got an update from the engineering team, this is expected behavior. The left side panel will just stay at "Feed", which is by design.

Comment: Any update on this issue and ETA for a fix? @meghana-msft?

Comment: The team is looking into it and we do not have any ETA to share.

Comment: So, Engineering expects that chat notifications from chat bots to stay broken and not return focus to chat pane and users should have to click twice to engage with the notifcation?  Even if  left side panel stays at feed at least the focus of the pane should return to the chatbot that sent the notification.

Comment: Currently it is by design. There is no plan to change the behaviour anytime soon.